# Multiple nested json to pandas dataframe when element names are not known or too many

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge json with almost a thousand+ elements. (See example with 35 elements)

The nesting goes as deep as 5 or 6 levels. It can go deeper for future data.

The issue I do not have control over the structure of the json or its nesting. I can't know beforehand the element names or the nesting levels they will have.

The standard solution of splitting each nested column to multiple columns using `pd.json_normalize` doesn't work for me. Even if I do it for one json file myself, I will have to go through the entire file, list down all the element names (item1, item2, etc. in the example), their nesting levels, whether parent or final node, and so on. And then for each such case, I will have to call the `pd.json_normalize` method again and again.

I can use `max_level` argument, or `record_path` argument to reduce such calls. But still I need to know the names of those parent elements, and the exact number of nesting levels under that beforehand. And have to hardcode that in the code.

Is there any way where the code can go through each item, one by one, and decide for itself whether it is final level or a parent level, then proceed with creating a dataframe column for it if it is final level, otherwise go deeper?

I am in search of a solution where column names are not required to be mentioned in the code.

A solution outside coding will also be fine. For example, opening json file in some other program, doing something, and then loading it to python, that's also okay. The main objective is doing this automatically without having to mentioning element names.

Please if someone can guide me towards a solution for this? I am reading a lot of such questions, but they mostly have solutions with column names mentioned in the code.

Thanks.

Attachment:

Json File

```
[
    {
        "item1": "1",
        "item2": "2",
        "item3": {
            "item4": "3.1",
            "item5": "3.2",
            "item6": "3.3"
        },
        "item7": "4",
        "item8": [
            {
                "item9": {
                    "item10": "5.1.1",
                    "item11": "5.1.2"
                },
                "item12": "5.2"
            }
        ],
        "item13": "6",
        "item14": [
            {
                "item15": [
                    {
                        "item16": "7.1.1",
                        "item17": "7.1.2"
                    }
                ],
                "item18": {
                    "item19": "7.2.1",
                    "item20": "7.2.2"
                }
            }
        ],
        "item21": {
            "item22": {
                "item23": {
                    "item24": [
                        {
                            "item25": "8.1.1.1.1",
                            "item26": "8.1.1.1.2"
                        }
                    ],
                    "item27": {
                        "item28": "8.1.1.2.1",
                        "item29": "8.1.1.2.2"
                    },
                    "item30": "8.1.1.3"
                },
                "item31": "8.1.2"
            },
            "item32": "8.2",
            "item33": {
                "item34": "8.3.1",
                "item35": "8.3.2"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Expectation:

```
    item1  |  item2  |  item3.item4  |  item3.item5  |  item3.item6  |  item7  |  item8.item9.item10  |  item8.item12  |  item13  |  item14.item15.item16  |  item14.item15.item17  |  item14.item18.item19  |  item14.item18.item20  |  item21.item22.item23.item24.item25  |  item21.item22.item23.item24.item26  |  item21.item22.item23.item27.item28  |  item21.item22.item23.item27.item29  |  item21.item22.item23.item30  |  item21.item22.item31  |  item21.item32  |  item21.item33.item34  |  item21.item33.item35
0    1  |  2  |  3.1  |  3.2  |  3.3  |  4  |  5.1.1  |  5.1.2  |  5.2  |  6  |  7.1.1  |  7.1.2  |  7.2.1  |  7.2.2  |  8.1.1.1.1  |  8.1.1.1.2  |  8.1.1.2.1  |  8.1.1.2.2  |  8.1.1.3  |  8.1.2  |  8.2  |  8.3.1  |  8.3.2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could unpack the data recursively:

```
def normalize(node, path="", row={}):
    for k, v in node.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            yield from normalize(v, path + k + ".", row)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for item in v:
                yield from normalize(item, path + k + ".", row)
        else:
            row[path + k] = v
    yield row
```

and create a dataframe from it:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(normalize(data[0]))
   item1 item2 item3.item4 item3.item5  ... item21.item22.item31 item21.item32 item21.item33.item34 item21.item33.item35
0      1     2         3.1         3.2  ...                8.1.2           8.2                8.3.1                8.3.2
1      1     2         3.1         3.2  ...                8.1.2           8.2                8.3.1                8.3.2
2      1     2         3.1         3.2  ...                8.1.2           8.2                8.3.1                8.3.2
3      1     2         3.1         3.2  ...                8.1.2           8.2                8.3.1                8.3.2
4      1     2         3.1         3.2  ...                8.1.2           8.2                8.3.1                8.3.2
5      1     2         3.1         3.2  ...                8.1.2           8.2                8.3.1                8.3.2
6      1     2         3.1         3.2  ...                8.1.2           8.2                8.3.1                8.3.2
7      1     2         3.1         3.2  ...                8.1.2           8.2                8.3.1                8.3.2
8      1     2         3.1         3.2  ...                8.1.2           8.2                8.3.1                8.3.2
9      1     2         3.1         3.2  ...                8.1.2           8.2                8.3.1                8.3.2
10     1     2         3.1         3.2  ...                8.1.2           8.2                8.3.1                8.3.2
11     1     2         3.1         3.2  ...                8.1.2           8.2                8.3.1                8.3.2
12     1     2         3.1         3.2  ...                8.1.2           8.2                8.3.1                8.3.2

[13 rows x 23 columns]
```

You can then `.drop_duplicates()` to get a single row.

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(normalize(data[0])).drop_duplicates()
  item1 item2 item3.item4 item3.item5  ... item21.item22.item31 item21.item32 item21.item33.item34 item21.item33.item35
0     1     2         3.1         3.2  ...                8.1.2           8.2                8.3.1                8.3.2

[1 rows x 23 columns]
```

Comment: Just clarifying. So the example that I gave, I will probably have same set of elements for different (say orders) another thousand times (1000 elements x 1000 orders). And columns are again a thousand. So, I first unpack elements for first order and create dataframe like you have, it will have a thousand rows, one for each element, with same data duplicated. Remove duplicates. Then go for next row (order), again thousand rows for second row, remove duplicates, and add second row to main df. Similarly for each row. Right?

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the answer I was looking for.

The point was:

1. To do it automatically without providing column names to normalize.
2. To do it fast as there are a lot of columns and rows in my case.

This link provides two possible solutions to this problem: one using recursive technique and one using iterative technique. Both yields the same output. One may choose the best suited for their approach.

[Article by Alina Zhang on flatting nested JSON in Python](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-flatten-deeply-nested-json-objects-in-non-recursive-elegant-python-55f96533103d)